# How to remove a wifi-hotspot on ubuntu gnome 14.04?

Tags: wireless

I created a wifi hotspot to use internet over my phone. But now I can't find any option to remove this wifi hotspot. It automatically turns on even if I close it. How can it be removed?

Answer (score 2):

To delete a hotspot connection go to the "network" icon in the right side of the Panel and choose  *Edit Connections*. In the new Network Connections window you can edit and delete connections.

Comment: it does not give me the option. is there an other option?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120415/how-to-remove-access-point-from-saved-list/120447

Answer (score 2):

I was also not able to find the network manager same like unity in Gnome desktop after the upgrade. Then I found that network manager is there but it is not linked to the settings menu. 

**Open terminal**, run `nm-connection-editor` 
This will open the connection manager for you (same as unity) where you will be able to make edits or changes to all kinds of networks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tools like ap-hotspot for hotspot creation then it is very simple to stop hotspot.

**sudo ap-hotspot stop**

Just run this command in terminal, Otherwise refer the link to manually disconnect the wifi hotspot.

[How To Turn Off Wifi Hotspot](http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. Wifi settings give an option to stop wireless hotspot(my_shared_connection) but it starts again itself. And there's no option to delete it. When i disable wifi hotspot, the hotspot name(my_shared_connection) appears in the wireless networks and only an option to forget it is there.