# How to permanently remove unused/unwanted access points appear in the network menu item Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, indicator

As shown in the image below, all the access points above the connected network are unused.

[image]

I want to remove this unused entries from the menu indicator. And I have already tried the solution explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/120447/270572). The solution works perfectly fine until I log in again. The entries reappear after new login. I want these things to be permanently removed from the machine.
Thanks in advance

**Solution** as per popular demand :)

> This problem was so annoying that I decided to demolish the OS. But before that I decided to 'grep' the directories in doubt in the root. And surprise.... there they are in the bluetooth directory (/var/lib/bluetooth/-device_name-/names). After removing them from the bluetooth devices, the ghosts in the network indicator disappeared. Thus the peace restored.

Comment: So it sounds like you don't want to see those irrelevant access-points from the menu? e.g. You don't want to see "Dell store" again.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin above... I said above, not below the connected network

Comment: Oh ok, I missed that part, thanks, how about trying to delete them within the "Edit Connections" option?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin thats the funny part, they are not even included in the 'Network Connections' entry. They are literally like ghosts.

Comment: @theDistantStar I was on the edge of the same "Demolish OS" decision so you helped me a lot. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was so annoying that I decided to demolish the OS. But before that I decided to 'grep' the directories in doubt in the root. And surprise.... there they are in the bluetooth directory (**/var/lib/bluetooth/-device_name-/names**). After removing them from the bluetooth devices, the ghosts in the network indicator disappeared. Thus the peace restored.

Comment: Could you please also add the above solution to the original question that helped you too?  ;-)