# Unwanted automatic connection to hotspot

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, hot-spot

I have a problem similar to that of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120415/how-to-remove-access-point-from-saved-list/120447).

A few days ago, I created a hotspot (`MyHotspot`) using `Create New Wi-Fi Network...` in order to share my wired connection with others via wifi, and now my laptop always automatically connects to the hotspot whenever I turn on the wifi.

I have tried to delete the hotspot both from `Edit Connections...` and by manually going in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and removing the hotspot with `sudo rm MyHotspot`. However, every time I turn on the wifi, for some reason, `MyHotspot` reappears and the laptop connects to it.

This is very annoying also because, for some reason, it also prevents me to use VPNs whilst connected with the wifi.

Any ideas on how to definitively get rid of the hotspot?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to delete the MyHotspot from Edit Connections. However, you can also disable the autoconnect by editing the MyHotspot profile, and unchecking the "Automatically connect to this network when it is available".

[image]

Comment: As I said in the post, deleting the connection from Edit Connections didn't work.  Also unchecking the "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" box does not work.

Comment: @Marce  Then, in `terminal`, `cd /etc/NetworkManager`, `ls -al`, and check that system-connections file mode is drwxr-xr-x, owner root:root. Then `cd system-connections`, `ls -al`, and check the file modes and they should all be -rw-------, owner root:root. If they're not, we'll have to `chmod` them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use

```
nmcli con show
```

then to make it stop autostarting and connecting

```
nmcli con mod <connection-name> connection.autoconnect no
```

This solved my problem atleast

Answer (score -2):

I’ve changed my hotspot password. I think that would disable any other devices or users that have connected in the past, not allowing connection unless I give them or enter the new password.