# Problem always start ubuntu in Wi-Fi hotspot (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, hot-spot

Every time I start the pc it shows a hotspot network connection, i was looking for a way to disable/delete it

Comment: Perhaps in Settings > Network?

Comment: Are you saying you want wifi to be disabled at boot until you enable it? Are you talking about being connected to wifi BEFORE you log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered that problem. I created a hotspot connection in my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) and it automatically enable that hotspot during startup, instead of switching to WiFi mode and search for available connections.

I resolved this by deleting the hotspot network entry (which includes the hotspot connection). You can follow the accepted answer here:
[How to remove access point from saved list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120415/how-to-remove-access-point-from-saved-list/120447)

```
ctrl + t {for terminal prompt}
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections 
sudo rm {wireless_hotspot_name}
```

This question might be a duplicate of above link, but I dont have priviledge right now to mark it as duplicate.